# Wordpress wp_nav_menu help

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am currently using wp_nav_menu to generate my nav menu.  Although everything is working and menu highlighting is working, how do you get child pages to be highlighted as well?

For example, I have a menu item named "Page" and it has 3 child pages under that.  So when I am in any of the child pages, I want the main Page to still be highlighted...how is that possible with using wp_nav_menu..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `body_class` function which WordPress has can help you out here.

---

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

---

What you'll want is `current-menu-parent` which you can utilise in your CSS. Not particularly well documented as far as I can tell, but this article helps:

---

http://www.designisphilosophy.com/tutorials/highlight-current-page-or-category/

---

Comment: Thanks...I totally forgot about utilizing the body class..but this will do for now...appreciate the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress will give the current page the class 'current-menu-item' so just add the css you want to that. e.g.

```
.current-menu-item {
background: #0077CC;
}
```

Edit:- You can target the child menu items with

```
.sub-menu .current-menu-item {
background: #0077CC;
}
```

Edit2:- Use this to hilight the parent menu item when on a sub page

```
.current-menu-parent {
background: #0077CC;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read the question thoroughly...It only applies it to parent pages and not child pages...

Comment: ...no perhaps what i wrote wasn't clear?  For example, I have a page named "A" and have 3 other pages which are child of "A".  On the nav menu, A is listed and highlighted when on the parent page.  But if I am in any of the 3 other child pages, I still want "A" to be highlighted...hope that is more clear...

Comment: You can use '.current-menu-parent' to do that.