# How do I target each menu different items on active state in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header, navigation

I want to change the color for each of the items of the top nav here on the active state:

For example, on the given page, and the category pages associated with this, I would like the header nav named "Thought Piece"  to be purple when the user is on that page.

Currently I have:

`builder-module-navigation li a,
.builder-module-navigation li.current_page_item li a,
.builder-module-navigation li.current-cat li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 0.2em .7em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: #666;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: transparent;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}`

I thought this would do the trick, but it's not:

`.builder-module-navigation  li.current_page_item #menu-item-78 li  a, 
.builder-module-navigation li.current-cat #menu-item-78 li a {
    color:#9900cc;
}`

How do I target the specific classes correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bit of PHP to do it as described in the WordPress [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting).

The relevant function is `is_page()` to determine which page you are on and some simple PHP logic to write a dynamic CSS attribute into the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` to find the current page and your CSS. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class and [Wordpress wp_nav_menu help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632123/wordpress-wp-nav-menu-help)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in Menus module it will add a class of current to the correct link automatically.

Learn how to use custom menus [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen).